# SQL Server: Store a database for portability

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have created a database with 8 tables in SQL Server Management Studio on Windows 7 as a non-admin user. In Visual Studio Express 2010 on the same user I am developing a WPF application that needs to access that database. However, the database file seems to be saved in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` and I cannot access that file from Visual Studio's Add Connection feature. Although I do have the admin password, files from that directory cannot be added. When I try to add it (after supplying the admin password) I get this message:

```
You don't have permission to open this file.
Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission.
```

Furthermore, during various stages of development I will need to create an .exe to send to a colleague for testing. Therefore, from what I understand the database needs to be included as a resource in the Visual Studio project. I have googled all day but found nothing relating to what I thought would be a common scenario. How can I add the database as a VS resource and access it from C#?

Thanks.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: For this type of project, consider [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)  It's a no-installation, in process database engine

Comment: @Ɖiamond: I added the error message. Note that simple adding the VS user to the database is not, I believe, the solution because I still need the database to be a VS resource so that I can transfer the .exe to another machine.

Comment: @Andomar: Thank you, but SQL Server is a specific requirement due to some tool that will go over the data at a later stage. However, I will take a look at SQLite for other project, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Sql Server is a server hosted database engine, you are not suppose to use the file directly.  What you may want to do instead is include an SQL script that will configure that database appropriately.  You can do this using the generate scripts task in SQL management studio.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks, I do see what you mean. I assume that the person who will receive the app will then have to install SQL server on his machine, no? In the general case of distributing an app to the public where the users may not have SQL Server installed, is SQLite the only really feasible option?

Comment: The error message comes from the operating system and is saying that you have insufficient permissions in Windows 7 to access the file. You can resolve this by changing the security settings on the folder, moving the file to a different location (detach from it in Management Studio, move it to your Documents folder, and then re-attach). As for packaging it as a resource, you would need to create an installation application that installs your exe, installs MS SQL Server (if not already installed) and then adds your database to the local MS Server instance.

Comment: @Ɖiamond: Your last sentence seems to be _exactly_ what I need to do. I just googled a bit to find any resources about automating the SQL Server install if it is not installed, but I cannot find anything really useful. Is this not as common a scenario as I had expected? How is the need for a database cannonically handled?

Comment: @dotancohen - Microsoft provide SQL Server Compact which contains an internal SQL Runtime engine that can be file based.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks. I see that SQL Server CE (and SQLite) both are missing stored procedures, which I would prefer to use. Also, right here on SO I see many bad comments regarding SQL Server CE. So I will have to ensure that SQL Server is indeed installed on the installers' machines'. I am surprised to see that this is such a headache!

Comment: @dotancohen The different versions match your different requirements.  SQL Server is aimed at a multi user client/server environment whereas CE is aimed at much smaller instances.  If you are deploying in an environment where you are simply passing the database file around why do you need the stored procedure?

Comment: @Bob: The application will only have one user at a time, but it will be used to manage inventory and derive patterns from (data mining). I would like atomic operations for moving inventory. Unfortunately I cannot use Debian + MySQL here, it needs to run on an existing Windows 7 machine and there is a very strong preference for a WPF frontend.

Comment: @dotanchen, SQLExpress may be more suitable, whilst it does require a server engine to be installed it does allow you to attach instances (ie provide the file). Alternatively You may be able use transactions to achieve your atomic operations.

Comment: @Bob: Thank you, SQLExpress does seem to be more along the lines of what I am looking for! Googling SQLExpress leads to many relevant articles. Also, as this question proceeds I am finding more relevant questions linked in the sidebar, and I see that SQLExpress is often the solution. Thank you! I would suggest that you mention SQLExpress as an answer so that I can accept it for future googlers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of the comments....

SQL Express will provide you with the functionality that you require.  Whilst it requires the machine to have the engine installed it does allow instance mode where you can directly attach database files in the connection string.

Additionally SQLExpress can be accessed via the MSSQL Management Studio tool (remember the default instance for this is `.\SQLExpress`